# understanding border attributes in css3

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble understanding what specific things these attributes do:

```
<style type = "text/css">
   h2{
      border-width: 15px;
      border-image: url("xyz.png");/*this understood*/
      -webkit-border-image: url("xyz.png") 25% repeat;

}
</style>
```

1) what is the border - width? Is the the width of the image applied or the width of the image is squished into(ex: 500X500 image squished into 15px height), it doesn't appear to be the length of the image applied and doesn't that already depend on the text?

2) In  `-webkit-border-image: url("xyz.png") 25% repeat;` what is this percentage value denoting? I understand how the repeat part manipulates the image being used, but what is this percentage denoting?

Answer (score 0):

```
  border-width: 15px;
  border-image: url("xyz.png");/*this understood*/
  -webkit-border-image: url("xyz.png") 25% repeat;
```

border-width: 15px; sets the border width to 15px, its pretty self-expanatory, i dont understand why you dont understand it.

```
-webkit-border-image: url("xyz.png") 25% repeat;
```

This is same like border-image except it makes sure that it works in chrome.

See , while you are working in css, you have to make sure the webpage you are designing behave similarly to all browsers.

-webkit- makes sure it works on chrome in a perfect manner
Similarly, 
-moz- is used for firefox

Comment: I don't understand it because, I don't know what would the image be if it consisted no transparency

Answer (score 0):

`border-width: 15px;` is the width of the border that will be applied to the image independatly of it's size

`border-image` is the image that will be displayed as border

`-webkit-border-image` This is same like border-image except it makes sure that it works in Safari.we

You can use also `-o-border-image` : to make it sure that it will work on Opera

you can see that exeple to anderstand more : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image